# Strange Refrigerator Problem

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual

I found this old mini fridge at the dump. It still had old sticky-notes attached to most of the oddly-shaped drawers.

Any idea what was kept in the bottom drawer?

[image]

Comment: Judging by the shape and location of the drawer, I'd say it's probably a bunch of ice trays... No idea about your puzzle, though. Tangential question: where can I get a refrigerator that has drawers like this?

Comment: @IanMacDonald -- that depends, are you using the massive drawer only for vodka? I'm just picturing the amount of vodka (and alcohol) you'd need to fill this thing if it was full-sized

Comment: @El-Guest: Is the drawer a leak-proof bucket, or is it expected to hold bottles? I had originally assumed bottles, but perhaps it would be better to just have a bucket. It would certainly be more impressive. And if you sat it beside your couch, you could just attach a straw.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: I had assumed bottles myself, but I like this bucket idea, it's much more space efficient. I'm not sure how well the champagne drawer would fare with all of the carbonation, but I'd imagine if this thing was actually produced, somebody would have thought of a way around that. As for the straw-in-the-vodka idea.....sign me up! I'd never leave my couch again.

Comment: @El-Guest How about [one of these?](http://www.bartendermixed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/speed-gun.jpg)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since there is a lateral-thinking tag, is it possible that the bottom drawer contained

> ice, to go along with the alcohol from drawers above it?

@Marc Zominy and @Phil H have also found that

> the alcohols in the post-it notes form a map of the world in terms of countries of origin of the alcohols in the fridge, implying that the bottom drawer contains something from Antarctica (in which there is lots of ice!)

Comment: Yes, of course! The drawers themselves are in close proportion to the continents. I'll mark as accepted soon.

Comment: @Chowzen This post isn't accepted yet

Answer (score 10):

I think I got it.

Here's my try on the lateral thinking process:

> Seems like the notes are arranged on an invisible world map centered on europe: Bourbon is from NA, Cachaça is from SA, Champagne is from France Europe, Vodka from Russia so Eastern Europe/Asia, Akpeteshie is from Africa, Foster is from Australia

So the reasoning leads to:

> An alcohol from Antarctica? I'm looking for it but didn't find yet. Or maybe then, it's the ice, as Antarctica is full of it but I can't find no typical alcohol from down there ;)

Edit: So I'll join El-Guest who had the same answer before me, but I add a piece of reasoning.

Comment: Maybe rot13(Tbqrg Nagnepgvpn)

Comment: Good answer! Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 6):

I think the bottom drawer contains

> Ice or snow

Because

> The post-its roughly map to the countries from which the beverages derive, making the bottom drawer Antarctica

A possible alternative is

> Lab-brewed beer: https://www.wired.com/2015/10/scientists-antarctica-drink-lot-maybe-much/